# Design of an auxiliary power supply for high voltage converter

Tags: power-supply, converter, half-bridge

I have a half bridge converter going from 270V to 24V, and I need to create an auxiliary power supply for my controller/drivers/etc. So I need a design with a high step-down ratio in order to go from 270V to 24V/12V, and I don't need much power. What are the best ways to achieve this?

Is it possible to get 24V at the output of the converter by stepping down the input voltage with a voltage regulator for a short time during start-up, then power the converter itself? Do you have a reference for this? I know it would imply high losses, but it would be only for a short time.

Thank you

Comment: Is isolation required?

Comment: Not necessarily, I can isolate later the signals that I need.

Comment: So this only needs to be during startup? And it can be self-powered thereafter? Or what are the power sequencing / switching concerns here if any? What about under fault conditions, incorrectly wired input or output, etc.?

Comment: Have a look at LNK3204.

Comment: Thank you, Jens. Indeed I found this linear regulator LR645 that can be used for SMPS start-up with a diode.  It first draws current from the input, then stops when the output voltage of the converter becomes grater than the output of the LR645.